# FASM и Vulkan API, Win32Surface возвращает 0x1 или Мы извращались как могли

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, vulkan

Мои сладострастные исходники на F'Asm уже не знают через что компилироваться. Пытаюсь на Vulkan'е хоть что-то вывести. И вроде всё шло замечательно до вызова vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(), он возвращает 0x1 и ни куда-то там, а в переменную, куда должен был вернуть созданный объект, а vkCreateSwapchainKHR ругается на эти шалости. К черту слова [исходники](http://dropmefiles.com/HrnJF) стоят тысячи слов (всё без вирусов, клянусь своим нулевым кольцом + FASM и всё необходимое, с вас только вулкан сдк).

```
format PE64 GUI 5.0
entry start
```

include 'win64a.inc'

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
      user32,'USER32.DLL',\
      vulkan,'VULKAN-1.DLL'

import vulkan,\
     vkCreateInstance,'vkCreateInstance',\
     vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties,'vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties',\
     vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices,'vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices',\
     vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures,'vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures',\
     vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties,'vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties',\
     vkCreateDevice,'vkCreateDevice',\
     vkGetDeviceQueue,'vkGetDeviceQueue',\
     vkCreateSwapchainKHR,'vkCreateSwapchainKHR',\
     vkQueuePresentKHR,'vkQueuePresentKHR',\
     vkGetInstanceProcAddr,'vkGetInstanceProcAddr',\
     vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties,'vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties',\
     vkDestroyInstance,'vkDestroyInstance',\
     vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR,'vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR'

include 'api\kernel32.inc'
  include 'api\user32.inc'

section '.data' data readable writeable
   VK_nst_ext            db 'VK_KHR_surface',0
   VK_nst_ext_2      db 'VK_EXT_debug_report',0
   VK_nst_ext_3      db 'VK_KHR_win32_surface',0
   VK_lay_val            db 'VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation',0
   VK_ext_DEV_KHR_SWAP   db 'VK_KHR_swapchain',0
   VK_Func_WIN_SURF   db 'vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR',0
   VK_Func_CR_DEV        db 'vkCreateDevice',0
   VK_Func_RepCall    db 'vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT',0
  _class TCHAR 'FASMWIN64',0
  _one  dd 0
  _null dd 0
  _Formule_ext dq 0
  _Formule_ext_1 dq 0
  _Formule_ext_2 dq 0
  _ms1 dq 0
  VK_INST_lay dq VK_lay_val
  VK_INST_ext dq VK_nst_ext, VK_nst_ext_2, VK_nst_ext_3
  VK_DEV_lay dq VK_lay_val,VK_ext_DEV_KHR_SWAP
  VK_DEV_ext dq VK_ext_DEV_KHR_SWAP

;==============================================
     VK:
     VK_Instance_h     dq 0
     VK_Videocard      dq 0
     VK_Device         dq 0
     VK_Queue_Graphic  dq 0
     VK_Surface        dq 0
     VK_Swapchain      dq 0

```
 VK_INST_EXT_n    dd 0
 VK_INST_LAY_n    dd 0
 VK_DEV_EXT_n     dd 0
 VK_DEV_LAY_n     dd 0

 Queue_es         dw 1.0
 VK_Family_index  dd 0
 VK_Image_count   dd 4
 VK_Clear_Val     dd 0, 0, 0, 1.0
```

;=============================================
     VK_View_Port:;++
     VK_VP_Cord  dd 0,0
     VK_VP_Size  dd 1366,768
     VK_VP_Depth dd 0,1.0

```
 VK_Scissor:
 VK_Sc_off   dd 0,0
 VK_SC_ext   dd 1366,768
```

;=============================================
      VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT:;+
         vdrccie_sType dd 3B9AF4F8h
                 dd 0;align
         vdrccie_pNext dq 0
         vdrccie_Flags dd 0x00000010
                 dd 0;align
         vdrccie_pfnCallBack dq Graphic_start
         vdrccie_pUserData   dq 0

```
  VK_AplicationInfo:;+
     VK_AplicationInfo_sType         dd 0;SType
             dd 0;align
     VK_AplicationInfo_PNext         dq 0
     VK_AplicationInfo_pAppName      dq WS_Title
     VK_AplicationInfo_applicationVersion db 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
     VK_AplicationInfo_pEngineName   dq WS_Title
     VK_AplicationInfo_engineVersion db 0, 0, 0, 1
     VK_AplicationInfo_apiVersion    dd 0x00400000

 VK_InstanceCreateInfo:;+
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_sType dd 1
             dd 0;align
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_pNext dq 0
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_flags dd 0
             dd 0;align
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_pAppInfo                dq VK_AplicationInfo
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_enabledLayerCont        dd 1
             dd 0;align
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_ppEnabledLayerNames     dq VK_INST_lay
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_enabledExtensionsCount  dd 3
             dd 0;align
     VK_InstanceCreateInfo_ppEnabledExtensionNames dq VK_INST_ext

 VK_Device_Queue_INFO:;+
     VK_Device_Queue_INFO_sType dd 2
             dd 0;align
     VK_Device_Queue_INFO_pNext dq 0
     VK_Device_Queue_INFO_Flags dd 0
     VK_Device_Queue_INFO_FamilyIndex dd 0
     VK_Device_Queue_INFO_QueueCount  dd 1
             dd 0;align
     VK_Device_Queue_INFO_Priority    dq Queue_es

 VK_Device_Create_INFO:;18 dword = 72 byte +
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_sType dd 3
             dd 0;align
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_pNext dq 0
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_Flags dd 0
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_QueCretInfCount  dd 1
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_QueCretInf       dq VK_Device_Queue_INFO
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_enb_Layer_Count  dd 2
             dd 0;align
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_ppEnb_LayerNames dq VK_DEV_lay
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_enb_Exten_Count  dd 1
             dd 0;align
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_ppEnb_ExtenNames dq VK_DEV_ext
     VK_Device_Create_INFO_pEnabledFeatures dq 0

 VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR:;+
     VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR_sType dd 1000009000
             dd 0;align
     VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR_pNext dq 0
     VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR_Flags dd 0
             dd 0;align
     VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR_Instance    dq 0
     VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR_HWND        dq 0

 VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR:;+
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_sType dd 1000001000
             dd 0;align
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_pNext dq 0
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_Flags dd 0
             dd 0;align                    
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_Surface       dq VK_Surface
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_minImageCount dd 3
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_Format        dd 44
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_ColorSpace    dd 0
             dd 0;allign
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_ImageExtent   dq VK_VP_Size
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_ImgArrLayer   dd 1
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_ImgUsage      dd 16
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_SharingMode   dd 0
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_QueueFamily_index_count dd 0
             ;dd 0;align
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_pQueueFamily_indexes dq 0;pointer
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_preTransform   dd 1
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_compositeAlpha dd 1
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_presentMode    dd 1
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_Clipped        dd 1
     VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR_oldSwapChain   dq 0
```

;===========================================================

```
 WS:
 WS_Title db 'VulkanRender', 0

 WS_STR:
 WS_cbSize dd 50h
 WS_STR_Style dd 0
 WS_STR_WinPr dq WindowProc
 WS_STR_mem_ext dd 0
 WS_STR_hz dd 0
 WS_STR_Instance_h dq 0
 WS_STR_Icon_h dq 0
 WS_STR_Cursor_h dq 0
 WS_STR_BackGround_h dq 4
 WS_STR_Menu_h dq 0
 WS_STR_Name_h dq _class
 WS_STR_IconSm dq 0

 msg MSG
```

section '.text' code readable executable

start:
     sub     rsp, 28h
     mov     rcx, 0      ; lpModuleName
     call    [GetModuleHandleA]
     add     rsp, 20h
     mov     [WS_STR_Instance_h],rax
     mov     [VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR_Instance],rax
     sub     rsp, 20h
     mov     rcx, WS_STR_Instance_h      ; hInstance
     mov     rdx, 7F00h          ; lpIconName
     call    [LoadIcon]
     add     rsp, 20h
     mov     [WS_STR_Icon_h],rax
     mov     [WS_STR_IconSm],rax
     sub     rsp, 20h
     mov     rcx, 0          ; hInstance
     mov     rdx, 7F00h      ; lpCursorName
     call    [LoadCursor]
     add     rsp, 20h
     mov     [WS_STR_Cursor_h],rax

```
 sub     rsp, 20h
 mov     rcx, WS_STR ; WNDCLASSEXA *
 call    [RegisterClassEx]
 sub     rsp, 40h
 mov     rcx, 0      ; dwExStyle
 mov     rdx, _class ; lpClassName
 mov     r8, WS_Title ; lpWindowName
 mov     r9, 10480000h   ; dwStyle
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-48h], (1920/2)-(1366/2) ; X
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-40h], (1080/2)-(768/2) ; Y
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-38h], 1366 ; nWidth
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-30h], 768 ; nHeight
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-28h], 0 ; hWndParent
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-20h], 0 ; hMenu
 mov     rax, WS_STR_Instance_h
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-18h], rax ; hInstance
 mov     qword[rsp+68h-10h], 0 ; lpParam
 call    [CreateWindowEx]
 mov     [VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR_HWND], rax
```

VK_Start:
     mov rcx, VK_InstanceCreateInfo
     mov rdx, 0
     mov r8,  VK_Instance_h
     call [vkCreateInstance]

`mov rcx, [VK_Instance_h]
 mov rdx, VK_Func_CR_DEV
 call[vkGetInstanceProcAddr]
 mov [_Formule_ext_1],rax

 mov rcx, [VK_Instance_h]
 mov rdx, VK_Func_RepCall
 call[vkGetInstanceProcAddr]
 mov [_Formule_ext_2],rax

 mov rcx, [VK_Instance_h]
 mov rdx, VkDebugReportCallbackCreateInfoEXT
 mov r8,0
 mov r9,_ms1
 call [_Formule_ext_2]

 mov rcx, [VK_Instance_h]
 mov rdx, _one
 mov r8,  0
 call [vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices]

 mov rcx, [VK_Instance_h]
 mov rdx, _one
 mov r8,  VK_Videocard
 call [vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices]

 mov r9,  VK_Device
 mov r8,  0
 mov rdx, VK_Device_Create_INFO
 mov rcx, [VK_Videocard]
 call [_Formule_ext_1]

 mov r9,  VK_Queue_Graphic
 mov r8,  0
 mov rdx, 0
 mov rcx, [VK_Device];first arg
 call [vkGetDeviceQueue]

 mov rcx, [VK_Instance_h]
 mov rdx, VK_Func_WIN_SURF
 call[vkGetInstanceProcAddr]
 mov [_Formule_ext],rax

 mov rcx, [VK_Instance_h]
 mov rdx, VK_Win32_Surface_CreateInfoKHR
 mov r8,  0
 mov r9,  VK_Surface
 call[_Formule_ext]

 mov rcx, [VK_Device]
 mov rdx, VK_Swapchain_CreateInfoKHR
 mov r8,  0
 mov r9,  VK_Swapchain
 call [vkCreateSwapchainKHR]

 add rsp, 20h`

Comment: *он возвращает 0x1* -- и что? Это *opaque handle*, там что угодно может быть. Если это первый такой объект в программе, то даже понятно, откуда взялась единица. А прикладывать исходники на файлообменнике на SO нет смысла: если кода нет *прямо в вопросе*, вопрос обычно закрывают.

Comment: Извращениям нет предела. Плюсую. Но, во имя богов, почему без макросов?

Comment: @insolor да я ж для себя делаю, вот и захотелось всё своими ручками, чтоб больше понимать как что работает, да и интересней так. У меня ещё отдельно в таком же формате pe-заголовок есть, ели как себя уговорил хотя бы на время не использовать.

Comment: @D-side opaque handle, спасибо, хоть что-то стало прояснятся. Но насколько я понимаю эти указатели используют сам АПИ, а я как раз передаю его в стандартной для АПИ структуре, но всё равно не работает, то есть я опять что-то не понял.